# How I can passing an array into getView method from GridView?

Tags: java, android

I do something like this:

```
grid = new GridView(this);

imagesPreviewH={1,2,3,4}

mAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(this, imagesPreviewH);

grid.setAdapter(mAdapter);

grid2 = new GridView(this);

 imagesPreviewH={5,6,7,8}

 mAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(this, imagesPreviewH);

 grid2.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,

 ViewGroup parent) {

  ImageView imageView;

 if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize             //  

 imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

 imageView.setImageDrawable(imagesPreviewH.get(position));

 int x = (int) (imagesPreviewH.get(position).getBitmap().getWidth() * 1.6);

  int y = (int) (imagesPreviewH.get(position).getBitmap().getHeight() * 1.6);

  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(x, y));

imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);


 imageView.setPadding(40, 20, 0, 1);


     imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        return imageView;

    }
```

But into GriView loading only {5,6,7,8}. How to do it two GridViews with {1,2,3,4} and {5,6,7,8} data, but not two GridViews with {5,6,7,8} and {5,6,7,8} data as is now?

Answer (score 1):

Your using `imagesPreviewH` twice. You need a different array for each gridview. Do this instead:

```
grid = new GridView(this);

imagesPreviewH1={1,2,3,4}

mAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(this, imagesPreviewH1);

grid.setAdapter(mAdapter);

grid2 = new GridView(this);

imagesPreviewH2={5,6,7,8}

mAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(this, imagesPreviewH2);

grid2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```